# Exception Handling Adventure

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have the following code skeleton

```
try {    
...    
...    
sysout("Please provide an input: ");
Thread.sleep(10000); //10 secs time given to the user to give the input. If the user doesn't enter the input it is throwing the exception, which is not being handled (with the custom message)
interact();  //This is a method that belongs to **expectj.Spawn** class
...
...    
} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("You have not given any input!Please try again!");

}
```

But i still get the following output-

```
Exception in thread "ExpectJ Stream Piper" java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException

at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:92)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:86)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:85)
at expectj.StreamPiper.run(StreamPiper.java:134)
```

Is there any other kind of exception i need to handle?

Comment: Are you sure that exception is being thrown on the same thread that your catching on?

Comment: I think so. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think scanner is better than BufferedReader.

```
ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ(10);
String cmd = "sh test.sh";
Scanner sc = new Scanner();
Spawn s = exp.spawn(cmd);
s.expect("Name");
String answer1 = sc.next();
s.send(answer1 + "\n);
s.expect("Password");
String answer2 = sc.next();
s.send(answer2+"\n");
.
.
.
//and so on...
```

Answer (score 7):

No, `IllegalBlockingModeException` is a subclass of `Exception` (a couple of levels down), so you are catching the right type. See the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/IllegalBlockingModeException.html).

However, it might be that the exception is being thrown from a different thread, in which case you would not see it in your try/catch block. The thread which has the exception thrown is `"ExpectJ Stream Piper"`.

Comment: But why would Stream Piper throw an exception?Because I'm able to successfully interact with the system when i call the interact(). It throws such an exception during runtime only when i don't interact after calling that method. Ok! If at all the exception is being thrown from a different thread, what should my approach be? I've never come across such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

There was no luck trying to get rid of the exception.So, instead of **interact()** we can use **bufferedreader** to take the input into a string and pass that string into **send()**. That is more convenient.

Comment: Is that possible you provide the sample code doing it? I face the same problem, with StreamPiper failing on bytes_read = inputStream.read(buffer);